# VSCode Active Text Editor Doesn't Work Even When Focused On A Text Window

Tags: vscode-extensions

On my VS Code extension, I'm trying to get the path to the current workspace. I've tried what it says on the documentation: `vscode.window.activeTextEditor` But this is always returning `undefined`.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Tried Code: `vscode.window.activeTextEditor`**

Comment: You should show your code.

Comment: @Mark I showed my code that I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually found the answer after a bit of messing around.

It actually was working, I just wasn't doing pulling up a window correctly.

1. **Go to the `[Extension Development Host]` window**
2. **Start your extension from the command pallet (`CTRL + Shift + P`)**
3. **In the `[Extension Development Host]` window, you have to open up a workspace or file.**

It works like this because it only senses for workspaces and files open in the Extension Host window.